# checkstyle - prohibit initializing object of type

Tags: checkstyle

suppose I have an external library with a class called Foo. I can't change Foo to have a private constructor, but I have a FooFactory class that I wrote.

So I have `FooFactory.getAFoo()` but I want checkstyle to catch any `new Foo()` in the rest of my code, to force using the factory.

I have this:

```xml
<module name="IllegalTokenText">
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_NEW"/>
    <property name="format" value="Foo"/>
</module>
```

but this doesn't seem to detect a `new Foo()`.

I could use a regex but this is much cleaner.

I had a similar problem with preventing extending a class:

```xml
<module name="IllegalTokenText">
    <property name="tokens" value="EXTENDS_CLAUSE"/>
    <property name="format" value="AndroidTestCase"/>
</module>
```

Neither of these checkstyle module seem to do anything at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IllegalTokenText](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalTokenText) checks for illegal text on the token itself, not on subsequent IDENT tokens or some such. So that is why it seems to do nothing in your case.

In your case, you may want to try using the [SevNTU Checkstyle](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle) extension, which offers a check called [ForbidInstantiation](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/blob/1.18.0/sevntu-checks/src/main/java/com/github/sevntu/checkstyle/checks/coding/ForbidInstantiationCheck.java) which might solve your problem. They have no documentation that I am aware of, so I am linking the source code with Javadoc. When you use SevNTU Checkstyle, be sure to use the right versions of regular Checkstyle and SevNTU Checkstyle, because not all combinations are compatible ([overview](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html)).

If that does not help, you will have to [roll your own](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html).